# What would I call the View Tab?

Tags: list-view

What would I call this view Tab?
And is the Edit Item considered to be within the Edit Ribbon? 
I'm trying to come up with the correct terminology.
Thanks

[image: photo of view tab within a task list]

Answer (score 2):

as per post 2007 when Microsoft introduced the Ribbon on almost every product, with 'ribbon' you mean the whole 'band' while Browse and view are tabs on the ribbon. Edit Item is a button on the VIEW tab.